# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4 + X^2)$ is the direct product of two rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

1. Prove that $R = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4 + X^2)$ is the direct product of two rings.

**Proof**:  I showed that $(X^4+X^2) = (X^2)\cap (X^2+1)$ and $R= (X^2) + (X^2+1)$. According the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we obtain an isomorphism of rings

$$
\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^4+X^2) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/X^2 \times \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1).
$$

2. Compute two non-zero elements $e,f$ of the above ring with the property that $e^2=e$, $f^2=f$, $ef=0$, and $e+f =1$.
3. Find all maximal ideals of $R$.

I'm not sure how to approach 2, or 3. Any help would be appreciated.

I am also wondering if $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2), \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1)$ are isomorphic to any well-known rings. For example, I know that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X) \cong \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Find the elements that go to $(1,0)$ and to $(0,1)$ by your isomorphism. Do you know the proof of the theorem, or are only using it as a black box?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1)$ is the ring of complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts by sending $a+ib$ to $a+bX$.

Comment: You should look at a constructive proof of the Chinese remainder theorem, but in this example the computation is simpler than usual, since $(X^2+1)+(-X^2)=1$. So, you can take $e=X^2+1$ and $f=-X^2$. Note that $e^2=X^4+X^2+X^2+1=X^2+1=e$, $f^2=X^4=(X^4+X^2)-X^2=-X^2=f$, $e+f=1$ and $ef=-X^4-X^2=0$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I see. Indeed, in the proof (in the case of two ideals) we define a homomorphism $g: R \to R/I \times R/J, \ r \mapsto (r+I, r+J)$ and obtain an isomorphism via the fundamental theorem. In our case, with $e = X^2+1$, we do have $$g(e) = (X^2 + 1 + (X^2), X^2 + 1 +(X^2+1)) = (1 + (X^2), 0 + (X^2+1))$$ and with $f = -X^2$ we have $$g(f) =(-X^2 + (X^2), -X^2 +(X^2 + 1)) = (0 + (X^2), 1 + (X^2+1)).$$

Comment: @conditionalMethod Any idea how to compute the maximal ideals?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$ has a very specific name: ring of dual numbers. It's defined for any field.